# Combining Real Time and Historical Sequence

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I am querying financial data using two different API methods:

- First method returns historical data in one batch.
- Second method provides real time data stream.

Naive approach is to process the historical data, stream it as IObservable, complete it and then switch to the real life data stream which never completes:

```
var historicalStream = GetHistoricalData(Datetime.Now.AddHours(-1), Datetime.Now);
return historicalStream.Concat(realTimeStream);
```

The problem with it is that some real time data ticks might be missed while historical stream is being processed. What's the best way to guarantee that not a single tick is missed (overlapping data is not an issue)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `Replay` all missed events in the real-time stream.

```
var liveStream = realTimeStream.Replay();
liveStream.Connect();

var historicalStream = GetHistoricalData(Datetime.Now.AddHours(-1), Datetime.Now);
return historicalStream.Concat(liveStream);
```

Comment: Works great, thanks! Just one clarification about it - does  every single tick is stored in the memory by liveStream even after dealing with the buffered ticks (which can lead to some bad consequences on a non ending stream)

Comment: It still maintains in the memory forever (in case another subscriber comes along). You can limit the buffer memory size by passing in a parameter when you create it.

Comment: ^ this.  Or you can use `Buffer` overload with `historicalStream.LastAsync()` which would close the buffer when `historicalStream` is done playing.